# Event ID:1026 System.InvalidOperationException at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single

Tags: linq, xaf, .net-runtime, entity-framework-migrations

I made the following changes to my DbContext

```
//public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }  //old
//public DbSet<TypePermissionObject> TypePermissionObjects { get; set; } //old
//public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; } //old

public DbSet<PermissionPolicyRole> Roles { get; set; }
public DbSet<PermissionPolicyTypePermissionObject> TypePermissionObjects { get; set; }
public DbSet<PermissionPolicyUser> Users { get; set; }
```

Now the following line of code is returning an error. When it should be returning false.

```
var compatible = db.Database.CompatibleWithModel(false);
```

The call stack is

```
Application: MyApp2.Win.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.InvalidOperationException
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.__Canon>, System.Func`2<System.__Canon,Boolean>)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer+<GetStoreAssociationTypePairs>d__15.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable+<SelectManyIterator>d__23`3[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable+<DistinctIterator>d__64`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]..ctor(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.__Canon>)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.__Canon>)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.FindAssociationTypePairs(System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1<System.Tuple`2<System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EntityType,System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EntityType>>)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.Diff(ModelMetadata, ModelMetadata, System.Lazy`1<System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.ModificationCommandTreeGenerator>, System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Sql.MigrationSqlGenerator, System.String, System.String)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.Diff(System.Xml.Linq.XDocument, System.Xml.Linq.XDocument, System.Lazy`1<System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.ModificationCommandTreeGenerator>, System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Sql.MigrationSqlGenerator, System.String, System.String)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.ModelMatches(System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.VersionedModel)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CompatibleWithModel(Boolean, System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseExistenceState)
   at System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].InitializeDatabase(System.__Canon)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(System.Action)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].PerformAction(System.__Canon)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(System.Action`1<System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext>)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(System.Type)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].get_InternalContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
   at System.Linq.Queryable.Count[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.Linq.IQueryable`1<System.__Canon>)
   at MyApp2.Win.Program.Main()
```

I have double checked the connection string

The projects reference EntityFramework 6.4.4

Event Viewer shows that the Source of the Error is .NET Runtime
Crosschecking the error time with output from Process Monitor ( from sysinterenals.com ) I see a NAME NOT FOUND error for EntityFramework.pdb
4 milli seconds earler there is a NAME NOT FOUND error for BiDInterface

[image: Proc Mon output]

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35243502/ef-update-database-causing-sequence-contains-more-than-one-element) indicates that I might have duplicate entries in my database.  I am not sure what is meant.

I tried changing to the following but it did not help/

```
  public DbSet<PermissionPolicyRole> Roles2 { get; set; }
  public DbSet<PermissionPolicyTypePermissionObject> TypePermissionObjects2 { get; set; }
  public DbSet<PermissionPolicyUser> Users2 { get; set; }
```

[Update]

I decided to delete the migrations and generate a new one.
When I attempted this I got the following error in the PM Console

```
PM> add-migration security
System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching element
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.<GetStoreAssociationTypePairs>d__15.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectManyIterator>d__23`3.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<DistinctIterator>d__64`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.FindAssociationTypePairs(ICollection`1 entityTypePairs)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.Diff(ModelMetadata source, ModelMetadata target, Lazy`1 modificationCommandTreeGenerator, MigrationSqlGenerator migrationSqlGenerator, String sourceModelVersion, String targetModelVersion)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.Diff(XDocument sourceModel, XDocument targetModel, Lazy`1 modificationCommandTreeGenerator, MigrationSqlGenerator migrationSqlGenerator, String sourceModelVersion, String targetModelVersion)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Scaffold(String migrationName, String namespace, Boolean ignoreChanges)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Design.Executor.ScaffoldInternal(String name, DbConnectionInfo connectionInfo, String migrationsConfigurationName, Boolean ignoreChanges)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Design.Executor.Scaffold.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Design.Executor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass4_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Design.Executor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Sequence contains no matching element
PM>
```

I have the following in the DbContext

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new RoleConfiguration());
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserConfiguration());
}
```

with

```
public class RoleConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<DevExpress.Persistent.BaseImpl.EF.PermissionPolicy.PermissionPolicyRole>
{
    public RoleConfiguration()
    {
        HasMany(x => x.Users).WithMany(y => y.Roles).Map(x => x.ToTable("PermissionPolicyUserPermissionPolicyRoles"));
    }
}

public class UserConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<DevExpress.Persistent.BaseImpl.EF.PermissionPolicy.PermissionPolicyUser>
{
    public UserConfiguration()
    {
        HasMany(x => x.Roles).WithMany(y => y.Users).Map(x => x.ToTable("PermissionPolicyUserPermissionPolicyRoles"));
    }
}
```

[Update]

I studied a new xaf project and realised that the configurations are not needed.

Now I try to run the migration without the configuration files I get

PM> add-migration security

```
 ystem.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching element
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.<GetStoreAssociationTypePairs>d__15.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectManyIterator>d__23`3.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<DistinctIterator>d__64`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.FindAssociationTypePairs(ICollection`1 entityTypePairs)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.Diff(ModelMetadata source, ModelMetadata target, Lazy`1 modificationCommandTreeGenerator, MigrationSqlGenerator migrationSqlGenerator, String sourceModelVersion, String targetModelVersion)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.Diff(XDocument sourceModel, XDocument targetModel, Lazy`1 modificationCommandTreeGenerator, MigrationSqlGenerator migrationSqlGenerator, String sourceModelVersion, String targetModelVersion)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Scaffold(String migrationName, String namespace, Boolean ignoreChanges)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Design.Executor.ScaffoldInternal(String name, DbConnectionInfo connectionInfo, String migrationsConfigurationName, Boolean ignoreChanges)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Design.Executor.Scaffold.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Design.Executor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass4_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Design.Executor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Sequence contains no matching element
PM>
```

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/net-framework-error-event-id-1026/35fb7784-2bfd-4187-b1fa-14d90225dbc2

Comment: https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t418166/how-to-upgrade-an-existing-project-to-the-allow-deny-permission-policy-migrate-to/

Comment: It seems I did too many things at once.
If I revert to the original data structure I can create a migration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think have done the security table upgrade in the wrong order.

I will need to roll back and proceed more carefully.